# GitLab's keys are not working after installing OpenSSH (Ubuntu)

Tags: passwords, key, gitlab, openssh

recently I came across something which I can't quite understand and I'd be grateful for any help.

In our company we use GitLab and I've my own key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa. It all worked until I installed openssh-server in order to connect to my workstation via ssh from home. It seems that while typing git pull in the console my GitLab's key is not available (?) and it want me to give a password for a git user. The message is like:

```
git@gitlab.mycompany.pl password:
```

I think that after installing openssh-server something must have changed, however I'm not quite sure why. After uninstallation - everything started working again.